# How do I make multiple request to the database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I would like to create a Voucher system and allow admins to create numerous voucher codes with diffrent values.

```
def randomString(stringLenght=8):
letters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
return ''.join(random.sample(letters, stringLenght))


class VoucherCreateView(CreateView):
model = Voucher
form_class = VoucherCreateForm
template_name = 'voucher/VoucherCreateView.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('voucher:voucher_create')

def form_valid(self, form):
    x = self.request.POST.get('value_x')
    x = int(x)
    for i in range(0, x):
        i = randomString()
        e = Voucher(voucher=i, money=self.request.POST['value_money'])
        e.save()
    return super(VoucherCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Models.py:

```
class Voucher(models.Model):
voucher = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True)
money = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
used = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Forms.py:

```
class VoucherCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
value_x = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
value_money = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

class Meta:
    model = Voucher
    fields = ['voucher', 'money']
```

I would like to add this to my sql using requests. Any idea on how to do this?

EDIT//
the solution is below, and if is the error like that, you need change `return super(VoucherCreateView, self).form_valid(form)` for example `return HttpResponse('success')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with `django-bluk-create` [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

for your case

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    x = self.request.POST.get('value_x')
    x = int(x)
    objs = [
        Voucher(voucher=randomString(), money=int('0' + self.request.POST['value_money']))
        for i in range(0, x)
    ]
    Voucher.objects.bulk_create(objs)
    return super(VoucherCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Working but have its error: (1048, "Column 'money' cannot be null") but isnt null..

Comment: one of possible reason can be as request data in json format, request.POST['value_money'] is not int, may be string value. just need to convert this safely to int. I have updated my code.